# Interest on self assessment tax

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india

Sr citizen individual assesses are exempt from advance tax requirement. Enough for them to pay self assessment tax before 31st July WITH OUT interest? Or, are they liable for interest payment?

V Sambasivan

Comment: Informed persons/tax consultants can please guide

Comment: Please update your question to indicate what country / jurisdiction you are referring to. Laws and tax regulations vary hugely across the world.

Comment: @sambasiva Assuming country as India, please edit the country tag if different

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are Resident Indian.

As per Indian Income Tax

> As per section 208 every person whose estimated tax liability for the year exceeds Rs.
>   10,000, shall pay his tax in advance in the form of “advance tax”. Thus, any taxpayer
>   whose estimated tax liability for the year exceeds Rs. 10,000 has to pay his tax in
>   advance by the due dates prescribed in this regard. However, as per section 207, a
>   resident senior citizen (i.e., an individual of the age of 60 years or above) not having any income from business or profession is not liable to pay advance tax.

In other words, if a person satisfies the following conditions, he will not be liable to pay advance tax:

1. He is an individual
2. He is resident in India as per the Income-tax Act
3. He is of the age of 60 years or above at any time during the year
4. He is not having any income chargeable to tax under the head “Profits and gains of business or profession”

Hence only self assessment tax need to be paid without any interest. Refer the full guideline on [Income tax website](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Tutorials/32-%20Exemption%20from%20pymt%20of%20adv.%20tax.pdf)